# Calling an overloaded function by using a generic variable as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-constraints

I want to extend the BinaryWriter class to be able to write a list to a stream.
I want to do this with multiple types of lists. I set up this generic function as an extension

```
public static void Write<T>(this BinaryWriter source, IEnumerable<T>items)
{
     foreach (T item in items)
          source.Write(item)//This doesn't work
}
```

Is this at all possible? I know write can handle all the built in types. I know there is the ability to constrain T to certain types, but I couldn't do it for int and double.

I only need it to work for ints, doubles, and bytes.

Comment: If it's only supposed to work for ints, doubles, and bytes, why not just write 3 overloads?

Comment: Basically, it only currently has to handle those 3, but future requirements might expand that to being able to handle other types.--edit words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dasblinkenlight's solution is probably the way to go, but here's an alternative:

```
public static void Write(this BinaryWriter source, IEnumerable items)
{
     foreach (dynamic item in items)
          source.Write(item); //runtime overload resolution! It works!
}
```

For more info on `dynamic`, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm going to try this out. It works like I want at least so far. I know it could have runtime errors, but I think it is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> I know there is the ability to constrain T to certain types

Unfortunately, the compiler has no idea that `T` is one of these types, so it has to complain.

> I only need it to work for ints, doubles, and bytes.

You can make three overloads then:

```
public static void Write(this BinaryWriter source, IEnumerable<int>items) {
    foreach (var item in items)
        source.Write(item);
}
public static void Write(this BinaryWriter source, IEnumerable<double>items) {
    foreach (var item in items)
        source.Write(item);
}
public static void Write(this BinaryWriter source, IEnumerable<byte>items) {
    foreach (var item in items)
        source.Write(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wanting to see if there was a way that I could make it be more dynamic since in the future I might need to expand how I use it. This was the solution I had come up with but I wanted to see how DRY I could make it. Thanks.

Comment: @Bear [Tim's way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015496/335858) is also valid, and it looks very cool, too. It may be considerably slower because of the dynamic type, but you can use it as a catch-all overload.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am thinking. I am not working on a realtime app so runtime costs are ok. (I already use a significant amount of system reflection to make the code more readable.) They both work, I'm going to try Tim's. You and I had the same though process but it just felt wrong typing the same lines in 3 different places.